# Oracle ORDS remote procedure call : payload and debug

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-ords

I am trying to develop some REST API and I am working with: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, Oracle ORDS and SQL Developer 17.3.1.279.

I already develop and test a GET API in order to prove that the db is REST-Enabled.

I try to develop a POST API and I am reading [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-remote-procedure-call-rpc-and-output-parameters)

My POST handler is:

```
declare
    lrow accounts%rowtype := null;    
begin   
    lrow.id := :id;
    lrow.account := :account;

    /*added to inspect the current value*/
    Raise_Application_Error(-20000, '*'||:account||'*');

    lrow.category := :category;
    lrow.address := :address;
    lrow.zipcode := :zipcode;
    lrow.city := :city;
    lrow.county := :county;
    ASADMIN.INSERTACCOUNT(lrow);
    :error := null;
exception
    when others then
        :error := sqlerrm;
end;
```

For each bind variable I create a corresponding in/out parameter in the handler.

I test the API with POSTMAN passing this object:

```
{
"id" : "18092018"
,"account" : "Buster Keaton"
,"category" : "TEST CATEGORY"
,"address" : "TEST ADDRESS"
,"zipcode" : "12345"
,"city" : "TEST CITY"
,"county" : "TEST COUNTY"
,"error" : null
}
```

and the response was "Cannot insert NULL in ..." then I add the raise application error in order to check what is the value passed that results as null.

I would like to know which is the common (or best) practice to debug a REST API and the way to "monitor" bind variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to run the anon block attached to the handler inside of SQL Developer to make sure it's going to work there first. So, does that work, in SQL Developer where you are doing the restful service definition?

*For others reading this question*, when you want to 'debug' and don't have access to the ORDS server logs:
If you get a 500 response when calling it from ORDS, it can be helpful to run ORDS in 'debug' mode.

There are two properties you can enable, debug and print to screen. ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/18.3/aelig/troubleshooting-REST.html#GUID-459D10EB-4E62-4D28-92EB-BE1886615E00))

This will show the stack dump from the back end in your browser - not something you ever want to do in 'prod' but since you're debugging, I'm assuming you're in a safe place.

Once that's on, make your call again -

[image]

Now you can see the ORA error code that's causing the 500 - and you can also probably see how ORDS is executing the anon plsql block - maybe you're not processing the inputs correctly...

[I talk about this here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/preventing-500-status-codes-with-oracle-rest-data-services/)

For your case specifically, you either have a typo or you are neglecting a value when it comes to making your call to INSERTACCOUNT().

Without seeing the spec for INSERTACCOUNT(), we're left to guess what might be happening.

Comment: in SQL Developer  I am defining the service in Module -> Template -> Handler -> SQL Worksheet. I will try to config the ORDS as you suggest. The INSERTACCOUNT is not doing something special. I would like to insert in the base table with different sets of fields based on the service used. In this case the error is raised because the all values "received" as payload are nulls. So the exception is correct but I can't figure out what I am missing in configuring parameters

Answer (score 0):

After commenting the response from [thatjeffsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156452/thatjeffsmith) I focus on service parameters and bind variables and I realize that my setup was completly **wrong**. I would like to share how I correct what was **my mistake**.

In the POST handler I use bind variable that I pass to the service in the body of the request but I define corresponding parameters as IN/OUT so the **SOURCE can be only HEADER or URI** and the bind variables result all null.

I found very useful theese articles: [Parameters and binds](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/parameters-and-binds-for-your-restful-services/) and [resultset](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/parameters-and-binds-for-your-restful-services-resultsets/).

I modify the handler deleting **ALL the IN/OUT parameters** because every variable (or JSON object) passed via request body are automatically "matched" with bind variables used in the handler.

Now I am working/studying on resultset in order to return the well formed json object with all the information needed to my app.

Comment: glad to hear you're making real progress!